# How to map apply_async exception to args given to apply_async function

Tags: python, pool

In my code I pass arguments (and the function to execute :-) to `pool.apply_async`.

Later, if the function causes an exception, is there an elegant solution to map the arguments to the exception?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import dill

def test():
    with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
        results = []

        for run, test in self.run_queue:
            result = _apply_async(pool, self._prepare_and_run_test, args=(run, test))
            results.append(result)

        for result in results:
            try:
                result.get()
            except Exception as error: # pylint: disable=broad-except
                self.log.debug(traceback.format_exc())
                # How can I know at this line which args was passed to the
                # object causing the exception?

def _apply_async(pool, func, args):
    payload = dill.dumps((func, args))
    return pool.apply_async(_run_dill_encoded, (payload,))
```

Comment: or maybe you should run all with single `for`-loop - to have together `result = ...` and `result.get()`. OR youi should keep together `append( [result, run, test] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions

Keep together `append( [result, run, test] )`
and later unpack it `for result, run, test in results:`

```
for run, test in self.run_queue:
    result = _apply_async(pool, self._prepare_and_run_test, args=(run, test))
    results.append( [result, run, test] )

for result, run, test in results:
    try:
        result.get()
    except Exception as error: # pylint: disable=broad-except
        self.log.debug(traceback.format_exc())
        print( run, test )
```

Or run all in one `for`-loop

```
for run, test in self.run_queue:
    result = _apply_async(pool, self._prepare_and_run_test, args=(run, test))
    #results.append(result)
    try:
        result.get()
    except Exception as error: # pylint: disable=broad-except
        self.log.debug(traceback.format_exc())
        print( run, test )
```

Comment: I don't think the "run all in one for-loop" is possible since result.get blocks. E.g. then it waits until the next function is queued removing the parallel execution scheme of _prepare_and_run_test.